# Console prompt to JTextPane

Tags: java

I have a problem. Need to redirect process.getErrorStream(), process.getInputStream() and process.getOutputStream() to JTextPane.
Process is situated in class A, and JTextPane is situated in class B, so there isn't direct connection between them. For this purpose I've create interface. So, I can call method informListener(String message) which appends line to JTextPane. But I can't find any solution which can solve my problem. Are there any nice and easy solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Use **ObserverPattern**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is couple of threads that read the data from the input streams returned by `get*Stream` methods and append into the text area.

Something like:

```
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream());
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    String line ;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        interfaceObject.informListener(line);
    }
}).start();
```

Just ensure that the appending to `textPane` happens in EDT using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

The following program works. (I am on OS X):

```
package snippet;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ProcessOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -lR");

        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                try {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }).start();

        int waitFor = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println(waitFor + " is the return");
    }
}
```

Check whether your command is being constructed properly. May be just print it out and see whether you are able to execute it from cmdline.

Comment: I've added comment with code samples as answer. Unfortunatly it doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex can you change it to a normal text pane and see whether it works? I couldn't see any problems with the code.

Comment: what means 'change to a normal text pane'?

Comment: I've added into the while System.out.println("line"), and there is no effect. Nothing is shown from console prompt

Comment: Because there might not be any output on the standard error.

Comment: @KMD I've also checked inputStream. Now need to check outputStream

Comment: @Alex OutputStream is for the input to the command. You need to worry about only `InputStream` and `ErrorStream`. I also added a fully working code. Check it out.

Comment: it works! My version works too. It was enough to remove 'start' from exec query. How can I set the charset?

Comment: You can pass it to inputStreamReader while constructing it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work. InformaListener calls another method. Here is it's code:

```
 HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
 HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();
 ...
 logTextPane.setEditorKit(kit);
 logTextPane.setDocument(doc);

public void onLogData(final String message) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), message, 0, 0, null);
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SummaryPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SummaryPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

And here is code to getErrorStream:

```
final String exec = "cmd /C start " + batStrPath + "\\upgrade-build.bat";
            final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exec);

            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        String line ;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            informListener(line);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Installer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            p.waitFor();
```